# opencv problems on Android

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv, edge-detection, javacv

Please we need help urgently, we are using openCv in Android (Java).
We are facing a lot of problems:

convertTo() doesn't work so we can't convert 3 channel image to 1 channel without passing it on cvtColor().

```
grayImg.convertTo(grayImg, CvType.CV_8UC1);
```

cvtColor() gives a weird output:

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(src, grayImg, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
```

Output of this line is the image repeated 4 times! 
The only way to get rid of this repetition is to add this line and the output is a white and black image but 3 channel so it crashes any coming function because it needs 1 channel image.

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(grayImg, grayImg, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGB,3);
```

canny() for edge detection:

```
Imgproc.Canny(grayImg, grayImg, 10, 100,3,true);
```

findContours() counts a horrible number of contours while number of objects in the image is only 2 input image is 3 channel bmp image and we convert it to Mat.

output image:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/36214963/canny.jpg

Thanks for your concern

Answer (score 4):

Try `BGR2GRAY` rather than `RGB2GRAY`.I had the same problem and I solved it through this.There is also a note in the documentation about this

> Converts an image from one color space to another.

The function `cvtColor` converts an input image from one color space to another. In case of a transformation to-from RGB color space, the order of the channels should be specified explicitly (`RGB or BGR`). **Note that the default color format in OpenCV is often referred to as RGB but it is actually BGR (the bytes are reversed).** So the first byte in a standard (24-bit) color image will be an 8-bit Blue component, the second byte will be Green, and the third byte will be Red. The fourth, fifth, and sixth bytes would then be the second pixel (Blue, then Green, then Red), and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually used opencv before, but I don't think `convertTo` is the answer your looking for.

By looking at the opencv documentation I found [this](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html):

> cvtColor - Converts an image from one color space to another

```
Mat color; // the input image
Mat gray(color.rows, color.cols, color.depth()); 
cvtColor(color, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
```

Or simply (and the function `cvtColor` will create the image internally):

```
Mat color;
Mat gray;
cvtColor(color, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
```

Comment: yes we already did this but the output is as shown in the image it's so weird..Thanks for you concern if you know what the solution please help us

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your first question correctly, you have two options to convert RGB images to grayscale ones.

Option 1: Convert the 3 channel image to 1 channel as you are trying to do.

```
IplImage *RGB_image = cvLoadImage("my_colored_image.jpg");
IplImage *GRAY_IMAGE = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(RGB_image), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
cvCvtColor(RGB_image, GRAY_IMAGE, CV_RGB2GRAY);
```

Option 2: Read the colored image as a grayscale image directly.

```
IplImage* GRAY_IMAGE = cvLoadImage("my_colored_image.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
```

I hope this suits you.

Comment: we tried to do this  too, we made the input image a grayscale image (got from matlab) and the same result keeps appearing !

Comment: would you please attach the input image and the portion of code giving these weird results,i'll be waiting for the link.

Comment: image:  https://dl.dropbox.com/u/36214963/canny.jpg
src=Utils.bitmapToMat(bmp); 
grayImg= new Mat(src.rows(), src.cols(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
Imgproc.cvtColor(src, grayImg, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY,1);

Comment: Actually i can't offer help now but i'll continue searching, 
(i think these topics relate to your Question,they might contain useful info also,especially last comments" ARGB_8888 stuff")     
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-opencv/8EoxpTb4W3E    
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-opencv/eSNsUQmnhAE    
h
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-opencv/_FMvZxP43ws/IyKf7jfqYbgJ

Comment: Thanks a lot for your concern, they released a new version and it worked it seems the old version had errors so no need bother yourself thanks a lot

Comment: For reference, the code in this answer is deprecated, IplImage is no longer used (replaced by Mat).